# Why can't I get Ellipsis to work on IE 11

Tags: css, user-interface, internet-explorer-11, ellipsis

I am trying to show the one line sentence followed by three dots (...) if the range goes beyond the line size.

I have used the below CSS which works fine on Mozilla and Chrome but does not work on IE 11.

```
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
padding-right: 20px;
```

Please let me know if this is due to any version issue on IE11 for this ellipsis or if there is a fix for it.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code too?

Comment: Give us more details, a demo will be perfect. IE 11 supports text-overflow.

Comment: @Ronald : Below is the HTML code. 
 <div class="qd-result-card__name-and-doctor" flex="">
                 <span class="qd-result-card__name qd-result- 
                                       card_tests_ordered" ng-bind-   html="vm.renderTestOrderNames(searchResultObj.testOrderName)"></span>
             </div>                 
qd-result-card__name - this is the css which holds the above style for this particular div

Comment: @Carnaru - Demo means do you want the screen shot of this not working on IE browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE ellipsis will only work on input fields if the `readonly` attribute is set to `readonly` or `true`.

```js
$('.all-javascript input').on('focusout',
function() {
  $(this).prop('readonly', 'readonly')
})

$('.all-javascript input').on('focusin',
function() {
  $(this).prop('readonly', false)
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 40px 20px;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap 
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chrome">
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, liberavisse signiferumque ex pri, diam brute epicurei cum ad. Ne mutat nostrud erroribus eam. At vis ignota appareat, vis tollit dicant cu. Est ceteros consequuntur an, an diceret iracundia maiestatis sea, an modo perfecto ocurreret mea. An mel quot philosophia. Elit dicant expetenda qui te.">
</div>


<div class="ie-11">
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, liberavisse signiferumque ex pri, diam brute epicurei cum ad. Ne mutat nostrud erroribus eam. At vis ignota appareat, vis tollit dicant cu. Est ceteros consequuntur an, an diceret iracundia maiestatis sea, an modo perfecto ocurreret mea. An mel quot philosophia. Elit dicant expetenda qui te." readonly='readonly'>
</div>

<div class="all-javascript">
<input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, liberavisse signiferumque ex pri, diam brute epicurei cum ad. Ne mutat nostrud erroribus eam. At vis ignota appareat, vis tollit dicant cu. Est ceteros consequuntur an, an diceret iracundia maiestatis sea, an modo perfecto ocurreret mea. An mel quot philosophia. Elit dicant expetenda qui te.">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE11 support white-space:nowrap; & text-overflow:ellipsis;

Try like this

```
h2 {
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis; 
    padding-right: 20px;    
}
```

Comment: display: block; did the job for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work in IE 11

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: If i remove display: block then it gets overlapped with the other div which is adjacent to this sentence

Comment: Can you give me your code i have to see the code for that